# PHP/Mysql: read data field value from lookup tables (split array)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 1 Mysql database with 2 tables:

DOCUMENTS
 ...
 - staffID
 .....

STAFF
 - ID
 - Name

The DOCUMENTS table assigns each document to a single or multiple users from the STAFF table therefore the staffID in the DOCUMENTS table consists of a comma separated array of staff ID's for example (2, 14).

I managed to split the array into individual values:

- 2
- 14

but rather than having the ID numbers I would like to have the actual names from the STAFF table - how can I achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated - please see my current code below.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
  organizations.orgName,
  documents.docName,
  documents.docEntry,
  documents.staffID,
  staff.Name,
  staff.ID
FROM
  documents
  INNER JOIN organizations ON (documents.IDorg = organizations.IDorg)
  INNER JOIN staff ON (documents.staffID = staff.ID)
")
or die(mysql_error());  


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $splitA = $row['staffID'];
    $resultName = explode(',', $splitA );
    $i=0;

    for($i=0;$i<count($resultName);$i++)
    {
        echo "<a href='staffview.php?ID=".$row['docName'].
            "'>". $resultName[$i]."</a><br>";
    }

    echo '<hr>';

}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to show the complete query I had in mind. If you don't need the staff ID you can just omit it.  Is there any significance to the organisation in selecting records from the staff table?

Comment: btw - probably better to edit the extra info into your original question, rather than posting an update as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your existing code *might* work where `documents.staffID = staff.ID` - that is where there is just a single staffID associated with the document?

You'd be better off adding a table to model the relationships between documents and staff separately from either, and removing or deprecating the staffID field in the documents table.  You'd need something like

```
CREATE TABLE document_staff (
    document_id <type>,
    staff_id    <type>
)
```

You can include compound indexes with `( document_id, staff_id )` and `( staff_id, document_id )` if you have lots of data and/or you want to traverse the relationship efficiently in both directions.

(You don't mention data types for your identity fields, but `documents.staffID` appears to be some sort of varchar based on what you say - perhaps you could use an integer type for these instead?)

**But** you can probably achieve what you want using the existing schema and the MySQL [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT 
    organizations.orgName,
    documents.docName,
    documents.docEntry,
    documents.staffID,
    staff.Name,
    staff.ID
FROM
    documents
INNER JOIN organizations ON (documents.IDorg = organizations.IDorg)
INNER JOIN staff ON ( FIND_IN_SET( staff.ID, documents.staffID ) > 0 )
```

MySQL set types have limitations - maximum membership size of 64 for example - but may be sufficient for your needs.

If it was me though, I'd change the model rather than use `FIND_IN_SET`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for you answer - greatly appreciated! 
My table setup is:

DOCUMENTS:

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
  docID     int NOT NULL,
  docTitle  mediumblob NOT NULL,
  staffID   varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  Author2   int,
  IDorg     int,
  docName   varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  docEntry  int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  /* Keys */
  PRIMARY KEY (docEntry)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

STAFF:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
  ID            int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  Name          varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  Organization  varchar(20),
  documents     varchar(150),
  Photo         mediumblob,
  /* Keys */
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

The DOCUMENTS table reads via a lookup table (dropdown) from the STAFF table so that I can assign multiple staff members to a document. So I can access the staffID array in the DOCUMENTS table and split that and I wonder if there is a way to then associate the staffID with the staff.Name and print out the staff Name rather than the ID in the results of the query. Thanks again!